# Replace value with Factor in r data.table

Tags: r, replace, split, data.table

I have a data set that has a column for a factor (in the example case, cut). It is currently set up like this:

```
library(ggplot2) # access to diamonds dataset
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(diamonds)[,list(mean_carat=mean(carat)), by=c('cut', 'color')]
```

I am trying to change all entries named "Fair" to "Good" because in my data set, the two entries are actually the same thing but notated differently. The syntax that I have been trying to use is:

```
data[which(cut = "Fair"), cut := "Good"]
```

and the output is

```
>Error: unexpected symbol in "data[which(cut = "Fair"), cut := "Good"]"
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `=` instead of `==`. Try

```
data[which(cut == "Fair"), cut := "Good"]
```

You also don't actually need the `which` statement:

```
data[cut == "Fair", cut := "Good"]
```